# Gradient descent self code: loss increasing gradually while optimizing -python

Tags: python, gradient, gradient-descent, non-linear

I'm trying to estimate the two parameter of the following exponential decay.
but the error(loss) is gradually increasing.

**I tried smaller learning_rate**, from 10 ^-2 to 10 ^-10
calculate differential again,
tried with different data set.

The parameters didn't bounce. Just steadily changing i.e. increasing or decreasing only.

[image]

[image]

[image: exponential decay]

code and the data is here:
https://github.com/psmuler/temp.git

What is wrong with the code?
If I change the minus of 
`tau - dif_tau/len(data), b - dif_b/len(data)`
in the line 35 into plus(+), it worked. But surely this is not the solution.
Maybe wrong with the partial differentiation.

[image]
or do I just misunderstand the very basis?

Thank you.

> If I change the minus of 
> `tau - dif_tau/len(data), b - dif_b/len(data)`
> in the line 35 into plus(+), it worked. But surely this is not the solution.

I've got
tau = 1291.352909
b = 0.14934105
on the data set 1_7,
which correspond quite well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `-` before `time`.

```
def dif_f0_b(time, tau, b):
    return (-1)*math.exp(time/tau) + 1
```

must be

```
def dif_f0_b(time, tau, b):
    return (-1)*math.exp(-time/tau) + 1
```

Comment: It worked. Silly mistake... Thanks for spending your time for me.